# Make a numpy array containing arrays of different shapes

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy I start with an array

```py
import numpy as np
blocks = np.array([arr], dtype=object)
```

with `arr` containing x elements. Now I have a while loop in which I take an element from blocks (an array). I do some operations on this block which results in 2 new blocks (arrays), I now want to delete the initial block I took from blocks, and replace it with 2 new blocks as such:

```py
blocks = np.delete(blocks, largestVarIndex[0], 0)
blocks = np.insert(blocks, 0, newBlocks[0], axis=0)
blocks = np.insert(blocks, 0, newBlocks[1], axis=0)
```

For 1 iteration I would want to go from [arr] -> [arr1, arr2]

But this gives the following error which I don't know how to solve, anyone that knows?

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1,193484,3) into shape (1,393216,3)

I tried using put but this also didn't work

Comment: Create a new array

Comment: @darthbaba but how do I do that? If I do np.array([block, newBlocks[0], newBlocks[1]]), the other arrays are nested in an array, while the new ones are on the correct dimension

Comment: It would help clarify what you really want to do if you added an example with smaller arrays

Comment: An example would be as such:

`blocks=[[1,2,3], [4], [5,6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]` we take a random block e.a., `[1, 2,3]` do some computations and get `newBlocks = [[1], [2,3]]` and we want blocks to result in `[[1], [2, 3], [4], [5,6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]` (the order of blocks doesn't matter) @PranavHosangadi

Comment: For the example I'd iterate on `blocks`, and use `append` or `extend` to add the new block element(s) to a new list.

Comment: If you get an error, show the WHOLE thing.  We shouldn't have to guess WHERE the error occurs.

Comment: @hpaulj I included the lines the error occurs at.

Comment: I want to see the whole error message, not the whole code.  You show 3 lines, which?  We also need to know about the arguments to the problem line.  There's no apparent relation between the `(1,193484,3)` shape and `(1,393216,3)`, nor any relation to any arrays that you describe.